# How to better merge change in state?

Tags: javascript, redux

Both updateUiActive and updateData return new copy of state.

I am using `updateData(updateUiActive(state, action), action)` to return a new version of state which contain first the properties updated with updateUiActive and after with updateData.

I would like to know if there is a more elegant and efficient way to do so.
Maybe using JS carry?

```js
const updateUiActive = (state, action) => {
  return dotProp.set(state, 'navigation.ui.active', action.payload)
}

const updateData = (state, action) => {
  const updatedData = state.navigation.data.map((x) => {
    x.isActive = x.id === action.payload
    return x
  })
  return dotProp.set(state, 'navigation.data', updatedData)
}

function navigationReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SET_ACTIVE:
      return updateData(updateUiActive(state, action), action)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use an action creator.

Comment: I recommend split and combine reducers. Can you post a full state of the navigationReducer?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, `redux` relies heavily on the `state` being immutable. You should not modify it, but return a new modified copy of it.

One option is to do it yourself (the spread operator from ES is usually very helpful for this).

Another option is using [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper). The syntax might be hard to get in the beginning, but for more complex state it helps you getting a better structure.

Comment: both functions in my example use map and dotProp so they are immutable. does it make sense?

Comment: I see, can you maybe post an example `state` and `payload`? I'm having a hard time visualizing it.